# pandas: if intersection then update dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, intersection

I have two dataframes:

countries:

```
    Country or Area Name    ISO-2   ISO-3
0   Afghanistan              AF     AFG
1   Philippines              PH     PHL
2   Albania                  AL     ALB
3   Norway                   NO     NOR
4   American Samoa           AS     ASM
```

contracts:

```
    Country Name                   Jurisdiction     Signature year
0   Yemen                             KY;NO;CA;NO   1999.0
1   Yemen                                BM;TC;YE   2007.0
2   Congo,                                  CD;CD   2015.0
3   Philippines                                PH   2009.0
4   Philippines                             PH;PH   2007.0
5   Philippines                                PH   2001.0
6   Philippines                             PH;PH   1997.0
7   Bolivia, Plurinational State of         BO;BO   2006.0
```

I want to:

1. check whether the column `Jurdisctiction` in `contracts` contains at least one two letter code from the `countries` `ISO-2` column.

I have tried numerous ways of testing whether there is an intersection, but none of them works. My last try was:

```
i1 = pd.Index(contracts['Jurisdiction of Incorporation'].str.split(';'))
i2 = pd.Index(countries['ISO-2'])
print i1, i2
i1.intersection(i2)
```

Which gives me `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

2. if at least one of the codes is present, I want to update the `contracts` dataframe with `new column` that will contain just boolean values

`contracts['new column'] = np.where("piece of code that will actually work", 1, 0)`

So the desired output would be

```
    Country Name                   Jurisdiction     Signature year  new column
0   Yemen                             KY;NO;CA;NO   1999.0              1
1   Yemen                                BM;TC;YE   2007.0              0
2   Congo,                                  CD;CD   2015.0              0
3   Philippines                                PH   2009.0              1
4   Philippines                             PH;PH   2007.0              1
5   Philippines                                PH   2001.0              1
6   Philippines                             PH;PH   1997.0              1
7   Bolivia, Plurinational State of         BO;BO   2006.0              0
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of a mouthful, but try this:

```
occuring_iso_2_codes = set(countries['ISO-2'])

contracts['new column'] = contracts.Jurisdiction.apply(
    lambda s: int(bool(set(s.split(';')).intersection(occuring_iso_2_codes))))
```

Comment: Thank you, it does exactly what I needed!